# How can I open a file with Far Manager editor using command line without launching a new instance of Far?

Tags: command-line, text-editors, far-manager

**Context**

When I using Far Manager, I would like to open Far Manager editor without navigating to the file (which could be on another drive, folder etc.) and pressing F4.

Instead I would like to open the file using command line:

```
c:>\<command in question> <full path to the file>
```

I do know the `far /e <file name>` command, but I would not like to open a new instance of Far Manager

**Question**

How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute a command where the path is prepended with `edit:`. For example:

- `edit:C:\Windows\win.ini`
- `edit:[10,] C:\Windows\win.ini` (open for edit with the cursor on the 10th line)
- `edit:[10,3] C:\Windows\win.ini` (open for edit with the cursor on the 10th line, and 3rd column)
- `view:C:\Windows\win.ini` (to view it)

Filenames with square brackets:

```
  If the filename contains square brackets (for example: "[1].txt"), then for the correct
opening of the file in the editor you must provide at least one delimiter (e.g. a space)
before the filename, or enclose it in quotation marks:

  edit: [1].txt
  edit:"[1].txt"
```

---

The functionality is provided by the `FAR Commands plugin` (installed by default).

```
  The FAR Commands plugin (FARCmds) provides a number of additional commands available in
command line via prefixes.

  In addition, the commands can be used in User Menu, in file associations, and in dialog
Apply Command (Ctrl-G)


 Command Line Syntax

  command:[options] object

  command - one of the following:
            view     - viewer
            edit     - editor
            goto     - jump to a file or folder
            clip     - put data in the clipboard
            whereis  - locate and jump to an object
            link     - create links
            run      - execute commands
            load     - load plugin
            unload   - unload plugin

  options - optional parameters, see corresponding commands descriptions.

  object  - one of the following:
            filename - name of the file to be viewed, edited or jumped to.
            path     - file or directory path to jump to.
            <command - intercept output of operation system command. Symbol < is obligatory.
```

---

I often use the file history (<kbd>Alt-F11</kbd>) to reopen files. You can easily open one of the last accessed files (<kbd>F3</kbd> to view, <kbd>F4</kbd> to edit, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open it as the last time), or search for a specific name in the history with <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-F</kbd>, <kbd>win.in</kbd>:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════ [win.in] ════════════════════════════╗
╟────────────────────────────── 19.03.2023 ───────────────────────────╢
║  Edit: C:\Windows\win.ini                                           ║
║                                                                     ║
```

Comment: many thx, that's it.